# regex against spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm not a regex guy, so I definitely need help on this.

All I want is to have a regular expression to validate if the user inputted on "username" will contain no spaces.

Currently, I have this structure:

```
if($('.username').val().length < 5) {
  $(".user_account_validation").html("Too shorty.").css('background-color', 'red');
} else if() {
}
```

As you can notice my `else if()` is still empty, and in that I want to place my validation. If the username has space I'll return a corresponding error message. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.  --[Jamie Zawinski](http://www.jwz.org/)

If all you want to know is if there are spaces in the input, the following will return -1 if there are no spaces in the input, and the index of the first space otherwise.

```
$('.username').val().indexOf(' ');
```

If you need a regular expression the following will return the index of the first whitespace, and -1 otherwise.

```
$('.username').val().search(/\s/);
```

Comment: This question is a perfect counter-example of Jamie's rule. This is because the language to match here actually IS regular.

Comment: @NiklasB. I will stipulate that it is a decent place to use a Regex, and in fact if the OP asked "how do I check for valid input", I would have pointed him to a Regex, but the quote is a knee-jerk response to, "I have problem X, how do use a Regex for it?".  Ideally, we should all look at *every* tool in our toolbox, rather than seeing everything as a nail to be pounded with a Regex hammer.

Answer (score 4):

No need to use a regex. You can simply use `$('.username').val().indexOf(' ') !== -1` to test if it contains any spaces.

Note that it does not prevent the user from entering tabs via copy&paste, but you need validation on the server side anyway, so if you check for things regular users won't enter over there, it's sufficient.

Comment: What about tabs, newlines, etc...?

Comment: Actually a regex would be really fitting here, why not suggest it (especially because it was asked for)?

Comment: Unless you use copy&paste or have a textarea you cannot enter tabs/newlines anyway. But you are right, if you want to block all whitespace a regex *is* better.

Answer (score 3):

you could use `indexOf` for just `' '`

```
else if ( $('.username').val().indexOf(' ') === -1 ) {
    //do stuff
}
```

but if you need to match anywhite space then use this

```
else if ( $('.uername').val().match(/\s/) {
    //do stuff
}
```